# how i save post with the current user without viewing all user list in the endpoint in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i was be able to create posting blog with django rest api and its almost ok, put i found that when i post request throw DRF endpoint dashbored,it views all the user list in dropdown menu,i dont wannt that,i want it to plug the current user without let it being edited in the endpoint
this is the code

```
class Tarh(models.Model):
    title         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    context       = models.TextField(default="nothing")
    user          = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publishedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating        = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    img           = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Serializer

```
class TarhSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tarh
        fields = ( 'title',"user" ,'context','rating','publishedDate','img','pk')
```

ViewSet

```
class TarhViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Tarh to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Tarh.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TarhSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

[i wanna hide this dropdown menu of users list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5NW3.png)

and just post the post with the current user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serializer.save(user=self.request.user)` should work. You can only make `user` field read_only, to disable dropdown menu:

```
class TarhSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tarh
        fields = ( 'title',"user" ,'context','rating','publishedDate','img','pk')
        read_only_fields = ("user", )
```

Comment: thanks very much..its works as expected ,but is this secure?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelkhalig sure, nobody will be able to post `user` data if you mark it as `read_only`. You can find more details in the docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields